# Possible to send Toast Notification in Windows 10 from a non-UWP C# app?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10-universal, toast

Toast notification in Windows 10 is great and there are many C# code samples written for Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app, but I couldn't find any sample written for non-UWP (Windows Classic Desktop in .NET framework).

I would like to have this feature in my next C# project but wanted to code it in non-UWP C#, it is possible? can anyone provide me some code samples?

Comment: Quickstart: Sending a toast notification from the desktop - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802768.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To send toast notifications from non-UWP apps in Windows 10, see **[Quickstart: Handling toast activations from Win32 apps in Windows 10](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/10/16/quickstart-handling-toast-activations-from-win32-apps-in-windows-10/)**.

That will show you how to register the COM server so that your users can click your toasts to launch your app (since toasts are persisted in Action Center, they can be clicked and launched at any point, even when your app is closed).

Comment: the link is written for C++ do you have a C# non-UWP version?

Comment: There's a C# code sample on the linked GitHub code sample here: https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/desktop-toasts/tree/master/CS

Answer (score 0):

You can use powershell embedded in the c#. This worked great with few dependencies and even runs in ssis.

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Management.Automation;

try
{

    // run powershell script

    var script = @"
    $ErrorActionPreference = ""Stop""
    $notificationTitle = ""Notification: Your script:" + popupMessage + @" has been completed successfully""
        [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime] > $null
    $template = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::GetTemplateContent([Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastTemplateType]::ToastText01)
    $toastXml = [xml] $template.GetXml()
    $toastXml.GetElementsByTagName(""text"").AppendChild($toastXml.CreateTextNode($notificationTitle)) > $null
    $xml = New-Object Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument
    $xml.LoadXml($toastXml.OuterXml)
    $toast = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification]::new($xml)
    $toast.Tag = ""Test1""
    $toast.Group = ""Test2""
    $toast.ExpirationTime = [DateTimeOffset]::Now.AddSeconds(15)
    $notifier = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::CreateToastNotifier(""Script Completed!"")
    $notifier.Show($toast);
    ";

    var _powershell = PowerShell.Create().AddScript(script);
    _powershell.Invoke();
    foreach (var errorRecord in _powershell.Streams.Error)
        Console.WriteLine(errorRecord);

}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

}
```